# Facebook request permissions example?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, authentication, permissions

I've been looking quite a lot for an actual example of how to implement asking for permissions with facebook login, but I couldn't find any. All I can find is the name of the permissions, advice on what to ask, but no examples.

The question is: Where and how can I ask for permissions using php or js? A bit of code would be very helpful. I am new to facebook developing and I've started reading all I can about facebook login and facebook api and trying to do a couple of small apps so I get used to how things work, but I am a bit stuck.

---

**Edit** I found this code, which seems to be what I've been looking for:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start with [Facebook PHP SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) , the key is to understand server-side login flow, as explained [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/), you can use this example as a start:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOU_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "user_photos"));
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did look there. I need an actual example, there is quite a lot of theory, but i'd love to see some code. For example the code to request access to user photos. Easy stuff, but **an example**

Comment: if you want users photos you need to request `array("scope" => "user_photos")` then redirect the user to `$loginUrl`, at this point he will login to facebook and or give your application permissions to acces the images he is tagged in (make sure you specify return url to your application hardcoded or in application settings, then you should be able to run an api command to fetch photos.

Comment: The `$loginUrl` only shows what information your app tries to access, but doesn't actually request the access, as far as I know. I may be mistaken, however. The difference is quite significant.

Comment: This is because you need to authorize the permissions first in the dialog, then back in your application you can run api requests because you gave the permissions.

Comment: Oh, seems to be ok, i've searched a little bit. Thanks

Comment: This actually seems to be what i've been looking for:
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'})